# iOS 8 Auto height cell not correct until landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I try to auto-height my cells in a UITableView. I have 3 UILabel in each cell and the last UILabel's size depends of text content. The last UILabel is fully displayed thanks to auto-height (iOS8) but sometimes a piece of text at the end of the cell is hidden. In this case, I have to landscape and I see the hidden text.

In my code, I have set automatic dimension in ViewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

I have set top, right, bottom, left constraints on my custom TableViewCell.

I have also the following lines before returning my cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```